# Updating the feature names into scikit TFIdfVectorizer

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, scikit-learn

I am trying out this code

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
import numpy as np

train_data = ["football is the sport","gravity is the movie", "education is imporatant"]
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(sublinear_tf=True, max_df=0.5,
                                                 stop_words='english')

print "Applying first train data"
X_train = vectorizer.fit_transform(train_data)
print vectorizer.get_feature_names()

print "\n\nApplying second train data"
train_data = ["cricket", "Transformers is a film","AIMS is a college"]
X_train = vectorizer.transform(train_data)
print vectorizer.get_feature_names()

print "\n\nApplying fit transform onto second train data"
X_train = vectorizer.fit_transform(train_data)
print vectorizer.get_feature_names()
```

The output for this one is

```
Applying first train data
[u'education', u'football', u'gravity', u'imporatant', u'movie', u'sport']


Applying second train data
[u'education', u'football', u'gravity', u'imporatant', u'movie', u'sport']


 Applying fit transform onto second train data
[u'aims', u'college', u'cricket', u'film', u'transformers']
```

I gave the first set of data using fit_transform to vectorizer so it gave me feature names like  `[u'education', u'football', u'gravity', u'imporatant', u'movie', u'sport']` after that i applied another train set to the same vectorizer but it gave me the same feature names as I didnt use fit or fit_transform. But I want to know how to update the features of a vectorizer without overwriting the previous oncs. If I use fit_transform again the previous features will get overwritten. So I want to update the feature list of the vectorizer. So i want something like `[u'education', u'football', u'gravity', u'imporatant', u'movie', u'sport',u'aims', u'college', u'cricket', u'film', u'transformers']` How can I get  that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In sklearn terminology, this is called a partial fit and you can't do it with a `TfidfVectorizer`. There are two ways around this:

- Concatenate the two training sets and re-vectorize
- use a `HashingVectorizer`, which support partial fitting. However, that does not have a `get_feature_names` method due to the fact that is hashes features, so the original isn't kept. Another advantage is that this is much more memory efficient.

Example of the first approach:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
import numpy as np

train_data1 = ["football is the sport", "gravity is the movie", "education is important"]
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english')

print("Applying first train data")
X_train = vectorizer.fit_transform(train_data1)
print(vectorizer.get_feature_names())

print("\n\nApplying second train data")
train_data2 = ["cricket", "Transformers is a film", "AIMS is a college"]
X_train = vectorizer.transform(train_data2)
print(vectorizer.get_feature_names())

print("\n\nApplying fit transform onto second train data")
X_train = vectorizer.fit_transform(train_data1 + train_data2)
print(vectorizer.get_feature_names())
```

Output:

```
Applying first train data
['education', 'football', 'gravity', 'important', 'movie', 'sport']

Applying second train data
['education', 'football', 'gravity', 'important', 'movie', 'sport']

Applying fit transform onto second train data
['aims', 'college', 'cricket', 'education', 'film', 'football', 'gravity', 'important', 'movie', 'sport', 'transformers']
```

Comment: Both of your approaches works good. I found HashingVectorizer useful for my purpose. Thankz for the answer :)

Answer (score 3):

I found this question while googling for the same issue that OP raised. Like [mbatchkarov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/419338/mbatchkarov) said Scikit-Learn's TfidfVectorizer doesn't natively support partial fitting.

HashingVectorizer is usually a great alternative, but it really depends on your use-case. Specifically, if you care very much about representing infrequent terms precisely, then collisions will hurt performance.

So I went ahead and wrote my own implementation of "partial_fit" for both TfidfVectorizer and CountVectorizer (see [here](https://github.com/ido-sh/online_vectorizers)). Hope it's useful for other people reaching this post. Note that this kind of partial fitting *does* change the dimension of the output vector given by the vectorizer since the whole point is to update the vocabulary (so take this into account when using in a pipeline).

Comment: Cool implementation. You should try submitting it as a PR to sklearn to see if that's something that might be useful upstream.