# Add document to scikit-learn's CountVectorizer?

Tags: scikit-learn, tf-idf, countvectorizer

I want to add a document to a pre-generated matrix using CountVectorizer.

```
word_counter = CountVectorizer()
words_matrix = word_counter.fit_transform(['first string','second string'])
```

Now I want to add another string '*third string*' to **words_matrix**. Extending the matrix - something like this:

```
words_matrix += word_counter.fit_transform(['third string'])
```

But I can't get it to work without fit_transform*ing* it all together.

Comment: What do you mean by extending? Do you want to update the vocabulary learned by the TfidfVectorizer?

Comment: I want to: fit_transform(['first string', 'second string']) & fit_transform(['third string']), so that the result is equivalent to: fit_transform(['first string', 'second string', 'third string'])

Comment: Yeah, thats called incremental learning and not possible to TfidfVectorizer. TfidfVectorizer is meant for smaller data, which could fit in memory at once. You should look into [`HashingVectorizer`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.HashingVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.HashingVectorizer)

Comment: [Here is a very cool example of Out of Core Classification](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/auto_examples/applications/plot_out_of_core_classification.html)

Comment: For those who HashingVectorizer doesn't meet their needs, see a possible alternative in my answer to this related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25154231/updating-the-feature-names-into-scikit-tfidfvectorizer/47639930#47639930). It's basically a custom implementation of partial fitting (or incremental fitting) for TfidfVectorizer and CountVectorizer.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/69156995/10495893